# How to form json body with dotted name of key

Tags: json, rest, kotlin, request

Need to form object in Kotlin for JSON body request with dotted name of key.

Nothing yet.

It's used the following object model in Kotling to form json body request:

```
val requestBody: Any = object : Any() {
        val user = user
        val paremeters: Any = object : Any() {
            val parameter1 = parameter1
        }
    }
```

to send the following json body request:
    { user: user,
      parameters: {
          parameter1: parameter1
     }
}

Now it's needed to send the following json body request:

```
{ user: user,
  parameters: {
      user.parameter1: parameter1
  }
}
```

So in Kitlin it's incorrect name with dot:

```
val requestBody: Any = object : Any() {
            val user = user
            val paremeters: Any = object : Any() {
                val user.parameter1 = parameter1
            }
        }
```

Could you propose some solutions for it?

Need to form json body for request with dotted names of keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think here you shouldn't be using an `object` for you `parameters` property, but rather a `Map<String, String>`, which allows keys with any characters:

```
val requestBody: Any = object : Any() {
   val user = user
   val parameters = mapOf("user.parameter1" to parameter1)
}
```

I believe it would be even nicer to create a named class for what you're doing rather than instantiated dynamic `object`s:

```
data class RequestBody(val user: String, val parameters: Map<String, String>)

val requestBody = RequestBody(user, mapOf("user.parameter1" to parameter1))
```